# nginx: split requests to very large directories to subdirs

Tags: linux, nginx

I have webdav server serving requests for items
like

- /path/to/directory/not_a_problem1.json
  and
- /path/to/directory/eeca9352c1ec475aadbd9d8c6e6aea94.ext. (long name of exactly specific number of chars,   this directory contains A LOT of files, 100k+).

Is it possible to modify requests so they will be to something like /path/to/directory/eeca/9352/c1ec4/eeca9352c1ec475aadbd9d8c6e6aea94.ext and also re-order existing files (if it's necessary)? (files not matching pattern should be left in place).

Reason - webdav server takes at least 20 seconds to answer every request to this directory (but <1 second on others).

Everything on ext4 formatted SSDs.

I can't modify logic on WebDAV server.

I can modify nginx.

I can move files on storage attached to WebDAV server.

Nginx runs on Ubuntu 18. Webdav server is in docker container.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "re-order existing files" and that non-matching files should be "left in place"?

Comment: @anaksunaman , "left in place" - this directory also contains files like sync_marker1233.json,etc - they don't cause issues right now. "re-order existing files" - I arleady have a lot of data some if there is way to fix access on nginx level - this mean that existing files should be in new places, right? not sure how to do it reliable